# Finding the start and stop indices in sequence in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching, sequence, indices

Suppose I have the sequence:

```
x = c( 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Is there an elegant way in R to return the start and stop indices of each sequence of 1s?

The answer should be a 2 column array with nRows = number of sequences of 1s:

```
startIndx = [ 1, 5, 7 ]
stopIndex = [ 2, 5, 9 ]
```

Thanks.

BSL

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your vector consists of 0 and 1 values:

```
which(diff(c(0L, x)) == 1L)
#[1] 1 5 7
which(diff(c(x, 0L)) == -1L)
#[1] 2 5 9
```

Otherwise you'd need something like `x <- x == 1L` first.

Answer (score 5):

Elegant way is

```
y <- which(x==1)
startIndx <- y[!(y-1) %in% y]
stopIndex <- y[!(y+1) %in% y]
rbind(startIndx, stopIndex)
#          [,1] [,2] [,3]
#startIndx    1    5    7
#stopIndex    2    5    9
```

Comment: Was looking at which ;) Excellent!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
y = rle(x)

stopIndex  = with(y, cumsum(lengths)[values==1])
startIndex = stopIndex - with(y, lengths[values==1]) + 1

#> stopIndex
#[1] 2 5 9
#> startIndex
#[1] 1 5 7
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this? [editted version according to suggestion of **alexis_laz**]

```
library(cgwtools)
res <- seqle(which(as.logical(x)))
rbind(res$values, res$values + res$lengths - 1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    7
[2,]    2    5    9
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you could replace your last line with `rbind(res$values, res$values + res$lengths - 1)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, much easier to read/understand now :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
startIndx<-rev(length(x)-cumsum(rle(rev(x))$lengths)[rle(rev(x))$values==1]+1)
stopIndex<-cumsum(rle(x)$lengths)[rle(x)$values==1]
```